# MSMQ Multicast queue on different server

Tags: c#, msmq, multicast

I want to send a message from my PC with MSMQ to a multicast queue on a server in the same network.
For some reason I don't seem to be able to do that, also, in the internet, I couldn't find even 1 sample of this.

Is it even possible to send a message from one computer to another computers MSMQ multicast queue?

Answer (score -1):

Troubleshooting is simple. You set up a multicast queue on the same machine as the sending application. If messages don't arrive here, you've either got the format wrong or not configured the queue correctly. Once that is working, set up a multicast queue on another machine. If that can't receive messages, your Windows firewall or network routers are blocking multicast traffic.